# Given $Y$ and $Z$ are two closed subspaces of a Banach space $X$, a condtion which implies $Y+Z$ closed in $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be two closed subspaces of a Banach space $X$, such that $Y\cap Z=\{\ 0 \}\ $. Show that $Y+Z$ is closed in $X$ iff there exists $\alpha >0$such that $\|y\| \leq \alpha \|y+z\|$ for all $y \in Y, z\in Z$.

I need help to do this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\|y\|\leq \alpha\|y+z\|$.

Let $(y_n+z_n), y_n\in Y,z_n\in Z$ be a Cauchy sequence. For every $c>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $n,m>N$ implies that $\| (y_n+z_n)-(y_m+z_m)\|<c$. We have $\| (y_n+z_n)-(y_m+z_m)\|=\|(y_n-y_m)+(z_n-z_m)\|\geq \alpha \|y_n-y_m\|$. This implies that $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $Y$ is a closed subset of a Banach space, $(y_n)$ converges towards $y$ and is henceforth a Cauchy sequence.

There exists $M$ such that $n,m>M$ implies that $\|y_n-y_m\|<c/4$. We deduce that for $n,m>Sup(N,M)$, $\|(y_n+z_n)-(y_m+z_m)\|\geq |\|z_n-z_m\|-\|y_n-y_m\||$, we deduce that for $n,m>N,M, \|z_n-z_m\|\leq 2c$ thus $(z_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence thus converges. We deduce that $(y_n+z_n)$ converges.

Suppose that $Y+Z$ closed. The projection defined by $p(y+z)=y$ is continuous since its graph is closed, we deduce that there exists $\alpha$ such that $\|p(y+z)\|=\|y\|\leq \alpha\|y+z\|$.